# How To Keep A Class Applied By A JavaScript Function Running Until Window Closed (Web Design)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know the title is quite confusing, so let me explain better here:

I have created a pop up appears in the bottom right corner of a page of my website. The pop-up functions just how I want it (Appears there when the page is opened from the start and can be 'x'ed out when the icon is pressed. But, as should be expected, when I leave the page to visit other pages of my website and come back, the pop up resets and is now there even if 'x'ed out. Is there a way I can make the popup stay hidden until the tab is closed or the visitor goes to a different website?

```js
function fcnx1() {
  document.getElementById("pop-up").classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
#pop-up {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7%;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  border-top: solid 5px rgb(25, 28, 31);
  border-bottom: solid 5px rgb(25, 28, 31);
  border-left: solid 5px rgb(25, 28, 31);
}

#pop-up p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: hide;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

@keyframes hide {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pop-up">
  <i onclick="fcnx1()" class="fas fa-times fa-2x" style="padding: 4%;             
        float:right;"></i>
  <p>Have your logo here! If you are interested in becoming a sponsor, feel free to email us at <a href="mailto:sponsor@beaverauv.org">sponsor@beaverauv.org</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at sessionStorage here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage. That should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need,

first of all, the popup starts hidden, so when window load event is fired, if there is no 'hidepopup' key saved on sessionStorage, the popUp will show, so  when you close it, the fcnx1 function will create the 'hidepopup' key on sessionStorage, this will last untill browser is close.

I also changed the animation on your css to an animated transition, this is more than enough in this case

Here is the window.sessionStorage [Definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

**And do not Try the snippet in here, it will not work,Stack Overflow`s fiddle is sandboxed and you can not access sessionStorage**

here is a codepen
https://codepen.io/Teobis/pen/ZRdQwL?editors=1111

```js
function fcnx1() {
       sessionStorage.setItem('hidepopup', true);
        document.getElementById("pop-up").classList.toggle("hide");
        }

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('hidepopup'))
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('hidepopup') == null){
    document.getElementById("pop-up").classList.toggle("hide")
  };  
})
```

```css
#pop-up {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7%; 
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  border-top: solid 5px rgb(25,28,31);
  border-bottom: solid 5px rgb(25,28,31);
  border-left: solid 5px rgb(25,28,31);
  transition:all 385ms linear;
}

#pop-up p {
  text-align: center;
  margin:5%;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="pop-up" class="hide">
    <i onclick="fcnx1()" class="fas fa-times fa-2x" style="padding: 4%;             
    float:right;"></i>
 
    <p>Have your logo here! If you are interested in becoming a sponsor, 
    feel free to email us at <a href="mailto:sponsor@beaverauv.org">sponsor@beaverauv.org</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work. The animation plays, but it plays as soon as the page is visited, not on the click of the button. Any ideas why?

Comment: [here is a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/161ynQ8FiGpDLBfpGkJMkN42nXXRmd8AN/view) showing the behavior of the pen, is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: My apologies for not including more details. The codepen works as I want it to, but when I put it into my own html/css files, it does not work. Matter of fact, the pop up does not even show up because of the the .hide applied to the pop up. I copy and pasted your code(code that appears to work), so I am not sure why.

Comment: I see, is there some javascript error when you put it with your code?